# How to add "nd" in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

At the moment I have, for example, a row like this in the DB:

```
Name       floor         building
Paul D.    32nd floor    C
```

Now I need to change "32nd floor" to "32<sup>nd</sup> floor"

If I directly copy paste it in the row in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio I lose the format and it's just "nd" as normal text.

Also tried it with:

```
UPDATE [Temp].[dbo].[OfficeFloor]
SET [floor]='32nd floor'
WHERE [Name] = 'Paul D.';
```

But I don't know how to add <sup>nd</sup> in the update query...

Is this even possible in SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server stores the **data** - not the formatting. That's a job for your **frontend** (web app, report - whatever)

Comment: You shouldn't be storing the text "nd floor" in the first place because it's redundant (as every value of that column will have the text "floor" in it). Just store the value `32` and do the formatting when you display the value. It's then also easier to display this information in different languages and formats.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, this was just an example. In fact I have the full address as value, for example: 123 Fifth Avenue, 32nd floor. So I have no choice, sometimes the address is just street + number...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can add it with this code:

```
UPDATE [Temp].[dbo].[OfficeFloor]
SET [floor]= '32' + nchar(0x207F) + nchar(0x1d48) + ' floor'
WHERE [Name] = 'Paul D.';
```

Answer (score 0):

The formatting of a value in a column is supposed to be the responsibility of the
application when data is presented and not the database. This aspect has to do with an important principle in the relational model ( which forms the very basic of T-SQL) called `Physical Data Independence`.

The data type say `varchar` of `floor` column is a property of the value stored in the database, and the internal storage format shouldn’t be your concern.